# xsl: loop over elements without xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input(irrelevant elements stripped for brevity):

**input.xml**

```
<Request>
    <Party>
        <PartyInfo>
            <PartyCode>WT</PartyCode>
            <ClientDate>01-01-2017</ClientDate>
        </PartyInfo>
        <General>
            <Phone>
                <PhoneNumber>555-1234</PhoneNumber>
                <PhoneCode>Cell</PhoneCode>
            </Phone>
            <Phone>
                <PhoneNumber>123-1234</PhoneNumber>
                <PhoneCode>Cell</PhoneCode>
            </Phone>
            <!--rest of children -->
        </General>
    </Party>
</Request>
```

I want to match any Party elements whose child, PartyCode, is equal to WT. Then, For each WT coded Party block, I want to match the child element Phone if its PhoneCode = Cell, and finally copy the contents as well as add 2 custom elements to it. Here is what's in place at the minute(currently matches each Party element of code WT and Phone of code Cell by index):

**stylesheet.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
<!-- identity transform, other templates -->
<xsl:template match="Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT'][1]/General/Phone[PhoneCode='Cell'][1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="PhoneCode">Phone</xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="UsePhone">Yes</xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT'][1]/General/Phone[PhoneCode='Cell'][2]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="PhoneCode">Phone</xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="UsePhone">Yes</xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT'][2]/General/Phone[PhoneCode='Cell'][1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="PhoneCode">Phone</xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="UsePhone">Yes</xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT'][2]/General/Phone[PhoneCode='Cell'][2]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="PhoneCode">Phone</xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="UsePhone">Yes</xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- 1 more 'group' of templates as above for WIT[3] -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've read in a few places that for-each loops should be avoided in xsl due to it being a more Imperative concept being used in a more procedural language, and that loops should be replaced with apply-templates and the like, but I'm struggling with how to group the matches like the above together. What kind of XSLT v2 solutions can I use to consolidate those templates into 1 while following best practice for XSLT?Note: I am using Saxon HE 9.7.0-8

Comment: I am afraid your "XSLT" snippet is not even well-formed XML (for instance `match="Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT'][1]General/Phone[PhoneCode='Cell'][1]>` does not having a closing quote for the attribute value) nor correct XPath (for instance, `Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT'][1]General` with `General` directly behing `[1]`) so I am not sure what that snippet is meant to show. If you want to match certain elements independent of the position, one forces you to use positional predicates like `[1]`, `[2]` etc. in your patterns, so I am not sure why you think you need to list them.

Comment: XPath and closing quotes corrected. ~What Its showing is that its currently matching a the first phone with a code of Cell on the first party with a code of WT, then the second phone of code cell of the first party, the 1st cell phone of the second WT party etc. does this clear anything up

Comment: And why do you need those positional predicates in the match patterns if you simply want to match `Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT']/General/Phone[PhoneCode='Cell']`? I don't understand what the problem is, there is no need to introduce positional predicates into match patterns if you don't want to treat elements differently based on position.

Comment: Thats what Im trying to eliminate; There are multiple templates in the stylesheet that run through the parties by index performing the same changes to the 1st and 2nd Phone elements of code Cell. I want to know if there a way to have just 1 template that will match all WT coded Parties, and perform the desired change on the Phone elements

Comment: As I said, using `match="Party[PartyInfo/PartyCode='WT']/General/Phone[PhoneCode='Cel‌​l']"` is easy and straightforward, not sure why that poses a problem.

Comment: @jbailie1991 - It might help if you showed your expected output for the given XML. Thank you!